# Shiny dplyr filter doesn't work after file upload

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I am building a shiny app to allow some of my non-data people to upload some files, some transformations, joins, and summaries come from those files, and some figures are displayed.

Will use one file and output for an example here. I am trying to do a filtering condition using dplyr on a column, but am getting this error after uploading the file.

```
Listening on http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"
  [No stack trace available]
```

Please note I am NOT trying to do a reactive condition (yet), just trying to filter out variables that are not needed to produce the desired output (2 factor pie chart in this case). Is there an error in the filtering or a way to file is uploaded?

The pipe for filtering and ggplot work fine outside shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv"))

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      plotOutput(outputId = "plots")

    )

  )
)
```

and my server

```
# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    data <- input$file1
    if(is.null(data))
      return(NULL)

    df <- data$datapath %>%
      filter(DQ.File == "In Compliance" | DQ.File == "Out of Compliance") %>% 
      group_by(DQ.File) %>% 
      summarise (n = n()) %>% 
      mutate(DQ.File = recode(DQ.File,
                              "In Compliance" = "Drivers In Compliance",
                              "Out of Compliance" = "Drivers Out Of Compliance"),
             freq = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2),
             label = paste(DQ.File, "-", paste(freq, "%", sep = ""))) %>% 
      select(-c(n, DQ.File))

    output$plots = renderPlot({
      df %>% ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = freq, fill = label)) +
        coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = 'black') +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "red")) +
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          legend.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid"))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to keep factors as such in the upload step or is my issue elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering outputs inside `observe()` is not recommended and in this case not even needed. Here's a better way -

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = T) %>%
    filter(DQ.File == "In Compliance" | DQ.File == "Out of Compliance") %>% 
    group_by(DQ.File) %>% 
    summarise (n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(DQ.File = recode(DQ.File,
                            "In Compliance" = "Drivers In Compliance",
                            "Out of Compliance" = "Drivers Out Of Compliance"),
           freq = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2),
           label = paste(DQ.File, "-", paste(freq, "%", sep = ""))) %>% 
    select(-c(n, DQ.File))
  })

  output$plots <- renderPlot({
    df() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = freq, fill = label)) +
      coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = 'black') +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "red")) +
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid"))
  })
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Not sure where I picked that up. Still new to Shiny, will research the purpose of that further. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @jarichardson Just go through RSudio's Shiny tutorials **in their order** and you'll be fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Answered my own question, but perhaps for someone else's sake:

Added read.csv into server with "stringsAsFactors = TRUE" but perhaps there's a better way?

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    data <- input$file1
    if(is.null(data))
      return(NULL)

    df <- read.csv(data$datapath, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
      filter(DQ.File == "In Compliance" | DQ.File == "Out of Compliance") %>% 
      group_by(DQ.File) %>% 
      summarise (n = n()) %>% 
      mutate(DQ.File = recode(DQ.File,
                              "In Compliance" = "Drivers In Compliance",
                              "Out of Compliance" = "Drivers Out Of Compliance"),
             freq = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2),
             label = paste(DQ.File, "-", paste(freq, "%", sep = ""))) %>% 
      select(-c(n, DQ.File))

    output$plots = renderPlot({
      df %>% ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = freq, fill = label)) +
        coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = 'black') +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "red")) +
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          legend.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid"))
    })
  })
}
```